# Разпознавание голоса через curl Yandex

Tags: php, apache, curl, распознавание-речи, yandex-speechkit

Подскажите пожалуйста, делаю следующий запрос:

```
$file = '/var/www/trysome/speach-service/Italian.mp3';
$uuid = '3be1f9ddf4944a529be45f7ca471868b';
$key = '3d79c4f5-dec0-43b2-8ea4-2790696c5722';
$url = "http://asr.yandex.net/asr_xml?uuid=".$uuid."&topic=general&key=".$key;

$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_UPLOAD => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    // CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('audio' => $file),
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: audio/x-mpeg-3',
    'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'
));
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print var_dump($result);
```

В ответ приходит:

```
igor@igor-H81M-S2V:/var/www/trysome/speach-service$ php -f indexroot.php 
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 213.180.193.202...
* Connected to asr.yandex.net (213.180.193.202) port 80 (#0)
> PUT /asr_xml?uuid=3be1f9ddf49b44529be45f7ca471868b&topic=general&key=3d79c3f5-dec0-43b2-8ea4-2790696c5722 HTTP/1.1
Host: asr.yandex.net
Accept: */*
Content-type: audio/x-mpeg-3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 10:43:52 MSK
* Server YaVoiceProxy2 is not blacklisted
< Server: YaVoiceProxy2
< X-YaReqFinish: 1438242232.212900
< X-YaRequestId: b90423dc-368e-11e4-a9e2-9277ca05b739
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 45
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 10:43:52 MSK
* Server YaVoiceProxy2 is not blacklisted
< Server: YaVoiceProxy2
< X-YaReqFinish: 1438242232.238032
< X-YaRequestId: b90423dc-368e-11e5-a9e2-9277ca05b739
< 
* Closing connection 0
string(45) "Streaming clients must specify audio field!
"
```

В заголовке указано что ответ `400` пришел, и:

> Streaming clients must specify audio field!

Это не верный запрос, или по указанным параметрам не может отработать сервер?
Могу я как то проверить, идет ли отправка аудио дорожки?

Answer (score 2):

```
$data=file_get_contents(realpath($file));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: audio/x-wav'));
```

Будет работать. Смотрите документацию и не пытайтесь постоянно упрощать  в коде...

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: спасибо, но щас уже не работаю над етим. Решил был проблему либой которая работала из етим сервисом, щас не помню как называется.